# Can I run ubuntu 12.10 in my pc?

Tags: 12.04

My system is:
Motherboard  : ZXI945LM4
Processor    : Intel Pentium 4. 2.4 Ghz
Ram          : 3 GB

Comment: You could run Ubuntu inside Ubuntu with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum memory requirement for Ubuntu 12.10 is 768 MB of memory(RAM) ,

5 GB of HARD disk space for Ubuntu and Pentinum 4 processor

but for 12.10 you need highly graphic supported motherboad that may not support "ZXI945LM4".

so you can use external graphic card or use ubuntu 11.10 that can work.

Comment: The graphics card can really be an issue. Afaik it's a GMA 950 chip, which is not well supported by Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

Download it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and follow these [installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest). 
If you are currently using Windows, follow these [instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) in order to create a bootable usb stick with the ubuntu image. Alternatively you could burn the image to a DVD. [How](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)?

Then choose "Try Ubuntu" in the dialog if you have booted from the DVD/ USB Drive.

If Ubuntu don't support your hardware, try Xubuntu / Lubuntu, the hardware requirements are less.